# Play audio multiple times while overlaying (i.e., concurrently) from command line

Tags: bash, audio, mp3

I'm trying to play a 3 tolls sound using a single toll audio file in bash. I want the sound to overlay each other.

The single toll duration is 4 seconds.

I want that:

- the first toll starts
- while the first toll plays, 1 second after the
  start, a second toll starts, overlaying the first, i.e., the second
  toll doesn't stop the first
- while the first and second toll play, 1
  second after the start of the second toll, a third toll starts,
  overlaying the first and second ones without stopping them

I'm trying

```
for i in 1 2 3; do mpg123 "single_toll.mp3" & sleep 1 ; done;
```

I get that the first toll is played entirely, and an indistinct sound is heard when the 2nd and 3rd tolls should be heard overlaying with the first.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually sox solves (inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634036/how-to-merge-several-audio-files-using-sox and modified according to sox man page):

```
sox single_toll.mp3 -p pad 1 0 | \
sox - -m single_toll.mp3 -p pad 1 0 remix v2 | \
play - -m single_toll.mp3 remix v2
```

The `remix v2` parameter is to be used because when sox remixes it reduces volume by 1/2, as man page explains.

For an arbitrary number of tolls, the second line may be repeated as many times as needed, actually `N-2` times